# What is the difference between Bootstrap 4's modal and scroll modal?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using quite a few modals on a site, and in mobile devices, the long modals don't scroll as they should; instead the site scrolls.  In Bootstrap 4's documentation there is a [scroll long content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content). I can't figure out the difference between that one and a normal modal. It looks the same to me.  I'm basically looking for a way for the modal to scroll when it gets to long in a mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference. bootstrap modal would scroll when it gets long. as they mentioned in document:

> **When modals become too long** for the user’s viewport or device, they scroll independent of the page itself. Try the demo below to see what we mean.

it shows the way modal will scroll. instead of modal content. the page would scroll which is a bit nicer in terms of UX, specially when your modal contains header and footer and content area get smaller.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I don't understand why my modal won't scroll in mobile devices.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Paula can you provide a url to check?